# Itext Pdf support rowspan only once?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

This is  part of my html source. I'm using Java, and I using iText 5.5.13.

In Chrome, this html is rendered how I want it to be, but if I open the PDF I actually created, it doesn't apply from the second rowspan

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS2GT.png)

[real_pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2zfU.png)

It makes me crazy.

```html
table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="0" 
       ...
         
          <tr height="100">
            <td rowspan="2" >this is first td</td>
            <td rowspan ="2" ">this is second td</td>
            <td>xxxx</td>
          </tr>
           <tr height="100">
          
            <td >this must be third</td>
          </tr>

      ....


        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I use tried so many things, but it always didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't organize it in a hurry and uploaded it.
This is my first time writing.
I solved this by putting pixel-by-pixel inline css in every html tag.